# ¿Cómo puedo entrar al admin de Django?

Tags: python, django

Soy nuevo trabajando con Django y estoy intentando acceder al admin de Django. No encuentro la contraseña ni el usuario para acceder.

¿Saben dónde están los datos o dónde puedo crearlos?

Answer (score 4):

Para poder ingresar deberás crear un superusuario un usuario que tiene control sobre todo lo que hay en el sitio.

Entra a la consola o la terminal de comandos y escribe:

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

Presiona enter y escribe tu nombre de usuario (en minúsculas, sin espacios), dirección de email y contraseña cuando sean requeridos.

No te preocupes que no puedes ver tu contraseña mientras la tipeas - así es como debe ser. Simplemente escribela y presiona 'Enter' para continuar. La salida de este comando debería verse así (nombre de usuario y email deberían ser los tuyos)

El codigo en consola se vera así

```
(myvenv) ~/djangogirls$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Username: admin
Email address: admin@admin.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
```

Una vez que hayas creado el superusuario, abres el navegador y digitas la url de tu sitio añadiendo `/admin` al final de la URL.

Por ejemplo, si la URL es: `http://127.0.0.0/`

Entonces en el navegador digita: `http://127.0.0.0/admin`

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que hayas creado el superusuario, solo debes añadir `/admin` al final de la URL.

Por ejemplo, si la URL es: `http://127.0.0.0/`

Entonces el administrador está ubicado en: `http://127.0.0.0/admin`

Comment: ¿"le pones" quiere decir accedes a la URL?

Comment: Sí, de esa forma se accede a la URL del Admin