# Django: login y registro de una class personalizada

Tags: python, django, login, class, registro

si quisiera crear un login y registro de un usuario de una class Apoderado que se encuentra en mi model.py y fue mapeada en BD con campos (nombre, apellido, correo,  usuario, contraseña...), mas no de usuario  administrador como podria hacerlo?
ayuda porfavor soy primeriso
Adjunto imagen del registro y login de la clase que deseo realizar, muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes apoyarte en el motor de gestión de usuarios que trae Django incorporado: [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/). Después, crea las vistas necesarias usando las plantillas que este te ofrece.

Comment: ¿te sirve esta página para lo del administrador? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133462/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-entrar-al-admin-de-django